# Error al operar con números complejos en C++

Tags: c++, números-complejos

Al definir un nuevo número complejo llamada *Pz* en el código, lo multiplico por otro previamente definido. Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'int' and 'std::complex')

Este es mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<complex>
int main(){
    cout<<"Parte Real:"<<endl;
    double i;
    cin>>i;
    cout<<"Parte Imaginiaria:"<<endl;
    double j;
    cin>>j;

    complex<double> z(i,j);
    cout<<z<<endl;

    complex<double> Pz;
    complex<double> P_z;

    Pz=2*z;
    cout<<Pz<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cambia esta línea:
`Pz=2*z;`
por:
`Pz=2.0*z;`

La razón es que el operador * que trabaja con números complejos toma argumentos de tipo `float`, `double` y `long double`. Como ves, no toma argumentos de tipo `int`, y por eso te produce el error.

Comment: Sí, era eso. Muchas gracias.